Configuration setting up selfhosted Gitlab Runner
I'm  learning how to set up self hosted runners in Gitlab with this video and have a question about the conceptional reason for configuring the .gitlab-ci.yml file in the way presented in the video.
In suggested configuation of the runner the execution program is choosen to be 'shell' and the shell parameter is choosen to be 'powershell' (see 5:25 in the video), so the relevant excerpt of the runner config file looks something like
[[runners]]
  name = "TestRunner"
  url = Blabla.com
  token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
 

Next - the part I not fully undestand - the setting up of a CI job the relevant excerpt of presented .gitlab-ci.yml file Inwould like to understand (see 7:00):

job_build:
    stage: built 
    tags: 
     - windows
    
    script:  
      - echo "Blabla"
      - cmd /c echo %PATH%
      - cmd /c echo %HOME%
      - cmd /c curl --version
      - cmd /c dir

   [...]


Question: What is the role of cmd command or/and why it is neccessary to use here?
I tried to make a script without - ie above replaced in the script part the cmd commands by
script:  
      - echo "Blabla"
      - /c echo %PATH%
      - /c echo %HOME%
      - /c curl --version
      - /c dir


but got an error.
Therefore my question is why it actually important to precompose all these shell commands by the cmd command? I thought that when above the shell parameter is set to 'powershell' it is clear that it's the powershell which executes all these commands, right? Why do we need cmd "additionally"? Naively it appears to be redundant; is there an indispensable reason for doing this that way?
So wouldn't precomposing cmd there be technically redundant as technically that all would already manageble by the powershell shell itself?
Therefore I not understand the role & neccessarity for precomposing cmd command there.
Here seems tacitly hierarchy relation: powershell can call cmd.exe but not converse.
Of course, there might be pure historical reasons. But I would like to understand if there are also conceptional reasons justifying this. Could somebody explain the involved mechanism behind this?

Got what error? You need to be as detailed as possible here.

@Destroy666: that the syntax is invalid. Then I tried to replace in the config file in shell line 'poweershell' by 'cmd' (...in order to text where the problem come from) but got message that cmd is invalid option. Why? Are ppeoply simply "to lazy" to implement cmd.exe as option for shell executor, or is cmd incompatible with gitlab runner framework incompativle for "deeper" reasons?

Please add the answer to comments into your question to make it better.

I mean, yeah, /c echo %PATH% is nonsensical, the syntax error is not a surprise. I'm more asking about what errors you got for other commands, e.g. the cmd or powershell versions. The whole question is quite confusing, are you wondering why there needs to be a shell at all? DId you try e.g. echo %PATH%?

@Destroy666: I'm wondering why - at least that how I understood the script part of the yml file - we seemingly need such nested "shell calls shell" mechanism. More precisely, in config file we have fixed powershell to be our executing shell program. Then, in the script part one calls in a command line the cmd shell. So why do we need here such "encapsulated" structure in sense of that one shell - powershell - proceeds calls of other shell - cmd? So why we actually need to work there with two shells subjected to such "nested hierarchy" to set up the runner job?

According to the gitlab docs, default shell on WIndows runners is pwsh. DId you try just e.g. echo %PATH% (or more functional Write-Output $Env:PATH) like I mentioned?
